# How to process batched data in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have a function which computes a new feature given several features of the data:

```
def my_func(f1, f2):
``
f1: torch.FloatTensor, shape = [1,2]
f2: torch.FloatTensor, shape = [1,2]
Returns
f3: torch.FloatTensor, shape = [1,2]
``
...
```

But my data is batched, so I have
f1 and f2's shape is [8,1,2]

I would like to apply my_func to get f3 with shape [8,1,2].

What is the idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: I think a more specific question would help you get answers soon. I have quiet a few doubts 1) Is batch size have something to do with your function? Then use the function at the unpacking side of data loader 2) if the function is independent of batch size use it in __getitem__() 3) if the function is dependent on your batch size you can even use it in the __init__() method of dataset.

Comment: Finally, you can be more specific or provide more info to get your answers faster and accurate.